# Codeigniter 4 model does not validate or updates $updatedField

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

This is my first time working with models in CI4. The below model works when fetching data, and also updating an excising record. But for some reason it does not validate any input data. I can leave the fields blank or fill them with a single character, they'd still update. Also when they update the $updatedField doesn't change (stays NULL).

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class GroupsModel extends Model
{
    protected $DBGroup = 'default';
    protected $table      = 'auth_groups';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;

    protected $returnType     = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;

    protected $allowedFields = ['name', 'description'];

    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';

    protected $validationRules    = [
        'name'        => 'required|min_length[3]|is_unique[auth_groups.name]',
        'description'     => 'required|min_length[3]',
    ];

    protected $validationMessages = [
        'name'        => [
            'is_unique' => 'Name has to be unique',
        ],
    ];
    protected $skipValidation     = false;
}
```

Here's the relevant code in the controller:

```
                  $groupmodel=new GroupModel();
                $group = $groupmodel->find($_GET["id"]);
                if(is_null($group)){throw \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException::forPageNotFound();}
                if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){$groupmodel->update($_GET["id"],$_POST);}
                helper('form');
                $data = [
                    'username'  =>  user()->username,
                    'title'    =>  'Groups',
                    'group'    =>  $group,
                    'errors'    =>  $groupmodel->errors(),
                ];
                echo view('panel/header', $data);
                echo view('panel/admin/group_edit', $data);
                echo view('panel/footer', $data);
```

Here's the table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `auth_groups` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Looking forward to your feedback!

Comment: Show us your `auth_groups` table schema. In addition, show us how you're executing the *update* query.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa I've updated the question to include the requested code and table schema.

Comment: How come your model's name is `GroupsModel` yet in your Controller, you instantiate it using a ***different*** name `$groupmodel=new GroupModel();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @steven7mwesigwa attentively pointed out there was a typo in the controller calling the wrong (?) model. This solved everything!

I was calling GroupModel, but the model was called GroupsModel.